# How to improve the time for searching a list over another list?

Tags: python

I was trying to change the value of the column 'names' on a dataframe for specific members of the dataframe. I'm trying to reduce the `len(names)` via labeling similar names with the same name, this is done with fuzzywuzzy. I have tried to figure out a way to do it with a nested loop:

```
for name in names:    
    for index in df_faces['Nombre'].index:
        name2 = df_faces.loc[index,'Nombre']
        try:            
            if fuzz.ratio(name, name2) >90:                
                df_faces.loc[index,'Nombre'] = name      
        except:
            pass
```

Where names is a list and `df_faces` is a data frame nxm-table-like, this is taking so long, because the data frame is about 1.2 millions entries and names is about 1k.

edit: what happen when i drop exceptions? well i guess some of the names are type float,i got this error and is in the fuzzywuzzy, should i transform the type of the data in order to drop the exceptions?

edit2: when i use the check_name(x) function i get this error, actually i cant figure out whats wrong

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6ce51e3e0802> in <module>
      3     return next(gen) if any(gen) else x
      4 
----> 5 df_faces.Nombre = df_faces.Nombre.apply(lambda x: check_name(x))

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4040             else:
   4041                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 4042                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4043 
   4044         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-14-6ce51e3e0802> in <lambda>(x)
      3     return next(gen) if any(gen) else x
      4 
----> 5 df_faces.Nombre = df_faces.Nombre.apply(lambda x: check_name(x))

<ipython-input-14-6ce51e3e0802> in check_name(x)
      1 def check_name(x):
      2     gen = (name for name in names if fuzz.ratio(name, x) > 90)
----> 3     return next(gen) if any(gen) else x
      4 
      5 df_faces.Nombre = df_faces.Nombre.apply(lambda x: check_name(x))

StopIteration:
```

Comment: try to write code without exceptions, `exceptions` are costly operation and will definitly consume a lot time

Comment: also instead from going through a name  go through df waise

Comment: thanks for the help, i edit the question about the exceptions, now about the waise, i google it whit python beside and i still have no idea what do you mean, would you mind to elaborate for me please?

Comment: here for each single name you are going through each df and do processing what i am suggesting is  for each data frame  try to replace name, then go to other df not the other way arround, this will save your memory read time

Comment: im trying it, it is working, i will make a benchmark whit time in order to see what happens thank for helpme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
def check_name(x):
    return next((name for name in names if fuzz.ratio(name, x) > 90), x)

df_faces.Nombre = df_faces.Nombre.apply(lambda x: check_name(x))
```

The `check_name()` function takes advantage of the generators and iterates to when the first value satisfying the condition `fuzz.ratio(name, x) > 90` and returns it, if there are no matches it returns `x`.

Through the [DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function, we vectorize the calculation on the dataframe and obtain the desired result efficiently.

I did tests on instances of a few tens of thousands of dataframe elements and a few hundred elements in the list of names and the solution I posted was about 6 times faster than the code you proposed in your application.

#### Explanation

The bottleneck of your algorithm is certainly given by **non-vectorization**. Iteration and pandas assignment operations are very slow, which is why it is good practice to vectorize your code whenever possible.

**Vectorization** is the process of executing operations on entire arrays. The entire point of vectorised calculations is to avoid Python-level loops by moving calculations to highly optimised C code and utilising contiguous memory blocks.

**Other suggestions**:
You could keep a map (dictionary or what you think is most appropriate) of the most common names *{key:name_from_df, value:name_from_list}*. This way you can search the map before calculating the fuzzy ratio. If the name is on the map you will have a time **O(log m)**, with m the size of the map. It's up to you to choose an appropriate m for your problem.

Comment: i try it but i get an error, i did not understand why is this, i also edit the question whit these information i was hoping you can help me to understand why is this

Comment: My error in copying and pasting `check_name() ` function. I have corrected the answer, now it should work properly

Comment: I also added some more comments to the answer.